# Ruby Motion, Rails 3.x, Devise login through custom api/v1/sessions_controller.rb

Tags: authentication, devise, rubymotion

I'm using this lucatironi tutorial to do my RM/rails/devise native authentication. I got everything working except one piece where I authenticate in the sessions_controller.rb

I'm sending in

{ session : { email: "test@five.com", password: "password" } }  (bubblewrap is forcing a 'sessions' node onto my JSON!)

resource_name is :api_v1_user

controller_path is "api/v1/sessions"

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
   warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :store => false, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
   render :status => 200,
       :json => { :success => true,
                  :info => "Logged in",
                  :data => { :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
  end
end
```

All I get is an alert in the app "Login Failed"

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out.

authenticate! doesn't return annything

has to be "authenticate" with no "!"

that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to call `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`? Given that the request is not coming from a rails-generated form, the token wouldn't be there.

Comment: Good suggestion. I didn't have this call in my sessions controller, but my posts and registrations controller work fine without this. I added it and it still fails to login.